# Finding secret message for password hash (knowing password and hashed password)

Tags: hash, passwords, modx-revolution

I'm currently using Evo CMS. I wanted to create an alternate backend to display data in a more elegant way than with Evo's default backend.

My current problem is that if if I want the login to work with the existing details I need to figure out how the passwords are being hashed, which I cannot seem to find anywhere in the source code.

Is there any way for me to find the secret key knowing the hashed password and the plain text password?

I **think** Evo is using Blowfish encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The "secret message" you speak of is called a salt. The way you are approaching this however is not ideal, as reverse engineering the login function (a function of MODX that may change or be updated in the future) will only work aslong as the password crypting and salting method of MODX stays the same.

If you want to use MODX's login functionallity but show a different backend after a successful login, the easiest way to go about it is to create a plugin attached to the [OnManagerLogin](https://docs.modx.com/3.x/en/extending-modx/plugins/system-events/onmanagerlogin) event.
Within that plugin you could write some code to redirect to a different management interface. Make sure to secure that management interface correctly. I would recommend implementing a type of token generation within the plugin that generates a token to your custom backend.
That way only a user with a valid token (generated before redirection) can use your custom backend.

If you want to use a custom login form, I would recommend either creating your own login functionality or importing the MODX API and running the `security/login` processor to authenticate your users via MODX.
The following example (untested!) can be used in a PHP script outside of MODX. If you plan on using it you're going to need to adjust the paths marked with `xxxxx`.

```
require_once '/xxxxx/config.core.php';
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH . 'config/' . MODX_CONFIG_KEY . '.inc.php';
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH . 'model/modx/modx.class.php';
$modx = new modX();
$modx->initialize('web');

$output = $modx->runProcessor('security/login', array(
            'username' => 'xxxxx',
            'password' => 'xxxxx'
        ), array (
            'processors_path' => '/xxxxx/core/model/modx/processors'
        ));
var_dump($output);
```